# nvm on Windows "out: No such file or directory. Stop."

Tags: node.js, mingw, gnu-make, nvm

I've got this error when installed nvm from github and running `nvm install 0.12.0` that I need to use:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make: *** out: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'node' failed
make: *** [node] Error 2
nvm: install v0.12.0 failed!
```

I'm running this from git bash.

How to fix this error? Should I create this `out` directory somewhere?

I've tried to add this to `nvm_install_source` function in nvm.sh:

```
nvm_cd "${TMPDIR}" && command mkdir -p "${VERSION_PATH}/out"
```

also

```
nvm_cd "${TMPDIR}" && command mkdir -p "out"
```

with no effect.

I've also try to create make file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir out
mingw32-make.exe $@
```

but then I got this error:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/jankiewj/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v0.12.0/files/out'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/jankiewj/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v0.12.0/files/out'
mingw32-make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'node' failed
mingw32-make: *** [node] Error 2
nvm: install v0.12.0 failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by installing [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).